# Problem with MacVim and XHTML

Tags: vim

I have a problem with MacVim. Whenever I try to change word inside a class attribute of an xhtml element, MacVim show up with error as shown below:

[image](http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/2527/picture1cfa.png)
[alt text http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/2527/picture1cfa.png](http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/2527/picture1cfa.png)

This is really anoying. I guess the error is come from omni-complete.
Plugins I'm using: autocomplpop, F6_comment, matchit, snipMate, NERDTree, fuzzyfinder_textmate

This problem is not occur with my GVim in ubuntu.
Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Searching for your error, I found [someone reporting a similar problem with omni-complete](http://markmail.org/search/%22processing+function+htmlcomplete%22).  The reply suggested that in older versions of omni-complete, the variable `g:xmldata_xhtml10s` was defined externally, and this sometimes resulted in problems.

Could you try updating the plugin and try again?

Comment: Thanks for your help.
The problem is reported in 2006 and it's also not my problem.
However, updating all my vim runtime files is a good idea. I'll try!